# Change the "belongs-on-serverfault" tag when a question is moved to serverfault

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

When a question is closed on StackOverflow as "belongs on ServerFault" and thus automatically moved to ServerFault, it retains the 'belongs-on-serverfault' tag.

It would make sense to either remove this tag automatically, or if you wanted to leave some indication that the question had been moved, remove it and add 'moved-from-stackoverflow' (or superuser, etc).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you're not going deep enough: these tags should not exist, period.

If you want something moved

- vote for it to be closed as "move to {x}"
- flag it for moderator attention

do NOT tag it "belongs-on-x".

(exception for superuser temporarily until we get that part of the code done)

edit: complete, we now auto-remove any [belongs-on-x] tags when a question is migrated from site to site.

Comment: I think it's worthwhile to have some indication that a question is community wiki because it has been moved, vs. someone specifically set it that way.

Comment: There are a lot of people who have 500 rep (for retagging) but not 3000 rep (for vote to close).

Comment: Why don't you ban/remove/block the tags then?

Comment: As much as I agree with you that the tags shouldn't be needed, it is nice to have a "flag" that everyone can see (until it gets moved) that that sort of question really belongs somewhere else. While it won't stop idiots from posting wherever they happen to be, it will stop the people who aren't sure if it really belongs on x or y.

Comment: Exception can now be edited, since this part for SU is done.

Comment: Do they get removed from the original site too?

Comment: @Jeff, I just found an example on SO where a question just got migrated to SU, but the belongs-on tag didn't get stripped, I saw it right after the migration.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401803/windows-hotkey-assistance

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good idea, since a "belongs-onserverfault" tag on Serverfault is akin to the "programming" tag on Stackoverflow.  Entire pointless and should just be inferred.

Answer (score -1):

Is it worthwile to have a "moved-from-stackoverflow" tag?

Comment: Usually you can tell, because someone has probably put a comment on it saying it should be moved to ServerFault.