# How to behave now I've got the 10K

Tags: discussion, reputation, 10k-tools

This is not a *factual* question of what I can do: [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-facilities-are-there-in-the-moderation-tools/4576#4576) lists the tools nicely.

It is more a question of how to behave based on the past experiences of those who've been 'over the top' longer.

If I understand correctly I have the ability to *find* questions potentially deserving of action more easily but does anyone have any advice on how to exercise the deletion ability.

Since I'm new to these heady heights I'll avoid going power crazy (for now ;)) but indications of how I can use this trust to help the site (perhaps by spotting questions that should be flagged to moderators faster) would help.

As I write this question I believe that there are 250 10K+ users (many recent) so there's a few of us that might benefit from it.

To clarify [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message) details asking to put this sort of into into an easily available message on reaching the threshold. What I'm looking for is *the info* I couldn't find a question/answer with that. None seems to be linked to on the question either.

Comment: So, you've gained some power... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message

Comment: If you are afraid, I can downvote you to solve this problem :]

Comment: The trembling on the edge problem was averted by getting pushed over by a bounty. Fortunate I don't think I could have taken the strain ;)

Comment: @random "Yes, I agree, I'll use my new powers wisely!"

Comment: close? is there a dupe somewhere? random's link is to a feature request to add something along the lines of a potted guide. I want the potted *guide*

Answer (score 15):

How about don't change at all?

The tools are there for you to assist in keeping the community organized. Use them wisely. It should not change the way you approach or interact with the site in any way. The novelty wears off eventually, and you get to realize that at the end of the day it is still your opinion against others, and since everything requires five people to agree, simply cast you vote towards what you feel is right.

Use them wisely. That's all you should do. There is no *expectation* for a sudden change or even involvement, since you are already actively involved.

It's the basis at which the tools are given, you are trusted enough not to change the way you have been, since this is what made people vote for you in the first place, and therefore brought you were you are.

<sub>Disclaimer: I need to take some of this to heart myself</sub>

Answer (score 14):

How I look at the 10k tools, is that they're there to help you keep doing what you've been doing all along.

- If you've been modding stuff, then now it's easier to find things to mod.
- If you don't mod much, then it's an incentive to start.
- If you still don't want to, then don't :)