# What do you do with the moderation tools?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, moderator-abilities

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to behave now I’ve got the 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20812/how-to-behave-now-ive-got-the-10k)
>   [“You have gained power. Here’s how to use it.” kind of message.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message)

For those who got to the 10K reputation, what do you do with the moderation tools? That is, what do you actively look for with them and how are they useful to you or how do you use them to help with the site?

Comment: And, what *should* people do with the tools? There is no instruction manual or even a guide... See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message

Answer (score 7):

I generally forget about them.

Seriously.

Every so often I'll go through and add a close vote to some if they're needed; or take a peek at what's highest voted and what's lowest voted.

But I'd wager that I don't even use the `tools` menu on 1% of my visits to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I generally check the list of close votes each morning to see any questions that need to be closed, I also look at the low voted questions and answers to see if there are any areas that can be cleaned up. Thats about it.