# Show notification when you pass a rep threshold

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You have gained power. Here’s how to use it.” kind of message.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message)

I just realized today on SO that I had a new capability to see the up/down votes on an item by clicking the vote total. I guess I haven't been keeping up enough on the blog to realize this feature got added at some point.

My suggestion is to show a notification whenever to the user whenever they enter into a reputation level that unlocks new tools that includes a link to a FAQ or other documentation explaining the new capability.

Also, I'd suggest a similar notification whenever a new capability is added for all users with enough rep to use it.

For example, you could use the same notification style as when you earn a badge.

Comment: I remember someone mentioned a feature request like this months ago...now where was it...

Comment: Here we go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message

Comment: It was a good idea before and it is still a good idea now.

Comment: @Ether: I agree, it is a great idea.

Comment: Possible Duplicate, yet no update on the status. It really should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

For gaining a rep-level - I'm pretty sure there always *was* such a message, certainly at some key points (maybe 3k? 10k?); it has been "some time", however...

I don't think this message applies to new site features; the blog, "meta", and self-discovery are the current route for that, AFAIK.

Comment: The last threshold I remember crossing was here on Meta at 3K -- no message ... It's a great idea, though.

Comment: There's no messages, from what I can remember.