# Editing other people's questions - what is advisable and what is not?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts)

I recently got some editing powers on SO.

I wanted to know to what extents is it advisable to go while editing other people's questions:
Should I keep only the tags in mind or should I go as far as converting all in-text "code snippets" to `code tags`?

What is *appropriate* editing?

Comment: I'd like to take this opportunity to mention my feature request here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message

Comment: @balpha and I'd like to take this opportunity to tell you I agree with you!

Comment: @balpha: 80 upvotes and still no action... sigh...

Answer (score 3):

Check out the FAQ on this: *[What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts)*

You can also take a look at: *[Should ‘Hi’, ‘thanks’ and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)*

And finally, check out all the questions here [tagged as **editing** or **etiquette**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/'editing'%20or%20'etiquette')