# What exactly does 10k give me?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the moderation tools available to high-reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users)

I just [got to 10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45373/statistics-of-how-fast-users-reach-10k-or-other-thresholds/64295#64295) (yay!) and I was wondering what are the new features I have available. I know that I can:

- Use the [tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-facilities-are-there-in-the-moderation-tools) (/tools)
- See deleted posts
- Vote to delete/undelete closed questions
- Inline retagging

Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Congratulations! You've also just hit 1k here :)

Comment: Congrats but it's a dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users/4576#4576

Comment: @thyrgle Actually, that answer only enumerates the different available lists open to 10k users. For example, it doesn't show that 10k users can view deleted posts.

Comment: @wai, but then how is that not still a duplicate question?

Comment: @thy I've seen that list. In fact, I have a link to it on my question

Comment: @Arjan It's not a dupe (at least of that question)

Comment: Then tell me *why* "What are the moderation tools available to high-reputation users?" is not a duplicate? Maybe it doesn't have all the answers, but duplicates are about *the question*, right? So how is that question not a duplicate? (And feel free to enhance the answer once you figure out more! Indeed, I feel inline retagging et al should be listed there as well.)

Comment: Oh well, maybe you're right after all! Still then, the other question being a FAQ, I guess any answer here should be merged into that question one day...

Comment: It's a duplicate -- if anything is missing from the FAQ, the FAQ should be updated.

Comment: @Arjan: It's not a duplicate of that question IMHO. That question is specifically about moderation tools. But there's a lot more for 10Kers than just moderation tools, such as the things NullUserException has mentioned and also there have been special offers from various sponsors that were only available for 10Kers. So I'd say that it's not an *exact* duplicate - that question is a subset of this one. This one is broader.

Comment: @Mark: The way the question was phrased in the body was "what are the new features I have available." To me, this does not mean "benefits of having 10k." Regardless, I don't believe the latter are worth documenting, as they are subject to external whims and may not apply to the same set of users the next time (or simply may never materialize again).

Comment: One more point: it makes users to post questions (or answers) like this on meta, just to let the world know of the milestone they're so proud of. Congrats :)