# What happened to the top bar messages for reputation milestones?

Tags: support, notifications

I remember clearly that when I had hit a few early milestones (like the Leave Comments one) an orange bar appeared at the top of the screen announcing the feature I had just unlocked.

When I reached 1000 rep on SO, no message bar was showed. I guess "show upvotes/downvotes" was not exciting enough to warrant a message.

Yesterday I hit 2000 rep, which now grants me the ability to edit people's posts, but disappointingly no orange bar was shown for this either.

Has the feature announcement message feature featuring the orange bar of doom™ been removed? Am I maybe misrecalling? I have been falling short of my waffle quota for a while, after all...

Comment: Back in my time we got no notification on nothing. You kids and your notifications.

Comment: I remember when you couldn't comment on posts.  Sheesh, people are so spoiled these days. (@Olafur)

Comment: I remember when the questions were tacked to a post in the middle of the town square and you had to ride on horseback for 40 miles through the desert to answer in person at the nearest StackExchange office.

Comment: @John, the desert?  I should have been so lucky!  I had to trek through snow, uphill both ways!

Comment: If you think it would be a nice feature to have, then please upvote ["You have gained power -- here's how to use it"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message)

Comment: @Popular Demand - Did I mention it was snowing in the desert?

Comment: @John, doesn't matter; you had a horse.

Comment: @Ether: already done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been around for nearly as long as you have been, but as far as I've been around, there has never been anything that announced you got new privileges.

Judging by the age and nature of [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/), I don't think it's ever been around.

> Right now, crossing one of the magical rep borders happens more or less unnoticed. People just gain the particular powers.

Maybe the notifications you are remembering are from the badge you earned just after getting the privilege to qualify for the badge?

Comment: Alright. I guess I haven't had enough waffles then. Re: badge. Yeah, that might indeed be what happened.