# I just crossed the 3K threshold! Any tips for responsibly wielding this power?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, privileges

Before I go power hungry and start closing random questions, are there any guidelines I should follow to be considered responsible?

Comment: For a start, I recommend reviewing the [close FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583) to understand in better detail the reasons why questions need to be closed, and to understand the different close reasons.

Comment: @Grace, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Anything else?

Comment: Don't disolve the senate, and if it's in any way avoidable, even if you think it's for a good reason, I'd steer clear of crossing the Rubicon prior to a dissolution of your army.

Comment: While not an answer, I'm almost certain someone is going to end up linking [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message).

Comment: Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance/32515#32515

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, close a question if it belongs on another site (that's usually obvious), or is clearly a duplicate of another question, or if it's obviously not a question or not worthwile on the site. Think before you vote to close a question. Is this *really* a duplicate, or is it just a similar question? If it's a subjective question, does it add value to the site? If you can, feel free to edit the question to make it better, particularly if it's just poorly worded.

tl;dr: Don't be a jerk.

Answer (score 3):

Basically if you think it meets the FAQ then reopen/keep it open. If it violates the FAQ then close it. Pretty simple. Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-questions+specific-question for some interesting past closings

Also of course be smart when closing. Don't close a question as a duplicate of a closed question, etc etc.

Comment: reason for the downvote is?

Answer (score 1):

Improve grammar, remove unnecessary tags, fix markdown errors and most of all, **be sensible**. Don't become a Wikipedian!

Comment: That's the 2K threshold you're thinking of.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the context, but why shouldn't he "become a Wikipedian"?

Comment: @C. Ross: because it'll distract him from his new duties on SO! Also: *Don't become a parent, a golfer, a lawyer, a short-order cook, a compulsive gambler, or an astronaut...*

Comment: looks like we are both victims of a drive by downvoter..

Comment: @Earlz: Well this is meta, I see this place as a sort of a side nab anyways. Most likely the downvoter was a "Wikipedian", they're not that thick-skinned as most of us - just joking, I don't really care who downvoted because he didn't say why :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't close **random** questions.

Comment: And don't close [random's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) questions either. ;)

Comment: But **do** close questions randomly - users expect it!

Comment: random doesn't care. @gno