# Privilege Wikis, we need your help!

Tags: discussion, privileges

I just deployed privilege wikis to meta see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges

This is in response to the ever so popular, [you have gained a power request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message).

[image: help]

Temporarily we are allowing all users on meta with more than **2000 reputation** to edit the wikis, we will then use these wikis as the global default wikis for all sites.

Generally we would like all the wikis to be approachable and clear, they should cover everything a user who hits the threshold should know. A screen shot or two may work in some cases.

500 hundred arbitrary meta points go to the most awesome contribution

Comment: Hmm - I thought it was going to be about disability. Can you change "abilities" to "superpowers"?

Comment: I assume since this is pre-production that the base page rep values are hard-coded...? I.e., comments says 50 [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/abilities), but 1 [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/abilities/comment).

Comment: Well, as a starting point, maybe copy and paste the relevant FAQ entries into each of those wikis?

Comment: There. I added a few.

Comment: @Jon, cache issue, its fixed now.

Comment: added on comment posting, tried to explain @username'ing. Also added a "please don't confuse answers with comments and new questions" to posting

Comment: bug report: ability to post links and images is shown as "new user" at the "other abilities" link list

Comment: 500 hundred arbitrary meta points?  Your bounty is about 49,500 rep shy. ;P

Comment: I just had to write you need to wait 48 hours to place a bounty and then you post _this_? HAX!!

Comment: @radp well thanks to Jarrod, you can see in the history that I did not cheat ... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66242/revisions :)

Comment: Is it me or the privs wiki are locked now?

Comment: @radp, just unlocked it again

Comment: @waffles: I'm guessing you're needing ever more help?

Comment: @Earlz ... yeah any more help would be ... hmmm ... helpful :)

Comment: Where at specifically? Are there any particular wikis that are in need of dire attention?

Comment: @Earlz A general review, the new privs need extra tlc, I think the flag priv is out of date

Comment: Temporarily for two years now.. :)

Comment: @waffles - At present is the reputation limit to edit wiki changed or it is same?

Answer (score 6):

I think the word "abilities" does not convey the intended meaning. I would change it to "privileges".

Comment: renamed to privileges

Comment: @waffles: I think my contribution was the most awesome don't you think? :)

Answer (score 3):

I think https://meta.stackoverflow.com/abilities is missing an entry:

```
10       Mark own posts as community wiki
```

[Ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49745).

Comment: +1, this would also be the perfect place to link to [the CW faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/146482)

Comment: edited, the ability kicks in in 10 btw .. not 15

Comment: @waffles: thank you very much for the correction. I have updated this post and [the](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49745) [other](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587) [places](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the one Peter pointed out, I think several things are missing:

- **200** - Get 100 rep on associated accounts.
- **15** - Participate in per-site metas (see [Super User's abilities page](https://superuser.com/abilities)).
- **20** - Talk in chat.
- **100** - Create chatrooms.
- **1000** - Create restricted chatrooms.
- **2000** - Suggest tag synonyms.
- **1000** - Vote on tag synonyms.
- **2000** - Edit tag wikis, assuming you have enough upvotes.
- **2000** - Website link in profile not nofollowed.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) (please contribute :))

Comment: Added most of these ... I may have missed the nofollow

Comment: bounty given cause the missing privs were really important and you did a fair bit of wiki editing, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Include information on the number of votes available each day for things like closing, flagging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the list is an entry for "Comment on other's posts." It should read "Comment on others' posts" (the posts belong to others, they do not belong to someone named Other). I'd edit it myself, but the titles aren't community-editable.

Comment: it's now "comment everywhere"

Comment: Sorry, gave the bounty to Simon, your were runner up if it makes you feel any better :(

Comment: @waffles, it does not. I will never forgive you for as long as I live.

Comment: @waffles, aw, shucks, I can't stay mad at you. We're cool.