# Privilege page for other users says "your reputation"

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation, user-interface, privileges

On the privileges page [for another user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/user/1) the reputation score is listed under **your reputation**, even though it's another user's score.

Comment: Jeff's going to see this, click your link, and then tag this no-repro since he won't see anything wrong.

Comment: I'm just waiting for Jeff to close this as `[status-no-repro]`...

Comment: @Grace: ! (15 chars)

Comment: We have a privilege page?

Comment: @TheLQ [It's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66242/ability-wikis-we-need-your-help) [new](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message/66241#66241)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, we don't really care about this case very much.

Why would you even need to view other people's privilege pages, again? What purpose does that serve? *Where is this even linked that a user could find?*

I view this as a URL-hacking developer function, so it's not exactly a high priority.

Comment: Because changing `Your` to `[usersname]` is so difficult...

Comment: If this isn't linked anywhere then downvoting this is silly; I'd rate pluralization bugs above bugs on dev-only testing pages that aren't even linked from the main site

Comment: Changing it to "[UserName] Reputation" reads like being smashed upside the head @the

Answer (score 3):

It would also be helpful to indicate when a user is a moderator (diamond):

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/user/2

It's just a little weird that he has 875 yet all privileges. It would also be nice if there was a link to a user's profile. It could be something like:

#### [Geoff Dalgas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2)' ♦ Reputation:

## 875

Comment: +1 - I was just about to post the exact same thing.

Comment: -1: he ain't got user ID 2 for nothin'. Joel the Apostle is only 4!