# Altruist and Benefactor descriptions are switched on privilege description page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, privileges-page

The descriptions for Altruist and Benefactor on the privilege page seem to be switched:

### Privilege page: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties

Altruist — manually award a bounty on a question of your own
Benefactor — manually award a bounty on somebody else's question

### Badge page

Altruist - First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question
Benefactor - First bounty you manually awarded on your own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch. <del>You can fix this yourself!</del> Any user with [at least 2k MSO rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66242/privilege-wikis-we-need-your-help) can fix this! All of the privileges pages are based on a "master" here at Meta Stack Overflow. Our noble, hypothetical editor would simply need to click the "edit wiki" link at the bottom of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties to make the changes.

Comment: And.... done. -- Your noble but not hypothetical anymore editor. :)

Comment: Thanks @Anna! You are indeed both noble and entirely real. I would've fixed it myself, but I got a new task for that "day job" thing just as I was finishing up this answer.