# Privilege page updates not being pushed to the rest of the network?

Tags: support, privileges-page

It's my assumption that the [Meta privilege pages act as templates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66242/privilege-wikis-we-need-your-help) for the rest of the network.

With this background, I had updated the [Edit Privileges wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) on Meta on [October 14th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66737/revisions).

[image: edit privileges page on Meta]

However, Stack Overflow still seems to show [the old privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) - why is this so?

[image: Edit privileges page on Stack Overflow]

Comment: btw @waffles the [set-bounties](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) wording is different on meta & on [su], can you please push the changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not strictly a bug, you just need to ping waffles to get updates pushed.

I always review the changes prior to pushing this across the network, it is too risky to automate this.

I just updated our templates, will be pushed tomorrow.

Comment: Ping - [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129330/missing-link-on-info-page) please. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - I just happened to see this from the other thread, it'll be in the next build.  Waffles is travelling but PRIVILEGE WIKIS WILL LIVE ON!

Comment: @Nick cheers! Didn't know devs can actually travel aka have a life... :D (on a more serious note, any better way to inform devs of such changes?)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - nah this is just fine...I saw it by my morning meta browsing, as it should be.  Expect things to be a bit slower this week though, everyone from around the world is headed to NYC for our yearly meetup starting today/tomorrow.