# Missing link on info page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, privileges, broken-link

There is a missing link on this page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

[image: broken](~/![enter image description here]

It also seems broken on SO. Could someone take a look?

Comment: Just a link to SO so we know when it's fixed http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like someone simply forgot to add that link.

It's pretty obvious what that was meant to link to, so [I fixed it here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66276/revisions); all privilege pages are wikis on MSO. The change will propagate to all other Stack Exchange sites in… actually I don't know, this is [done manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110233/privilege-page-updates-not-being-pushed-to-the-rest-of-the-network/110241#110241).

Comment: Did you ping Sir Waffles to ensure that your update gets pushed?

Comment: @TheEstablishment - I took the liberty to [do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110233/privilege-page-updates-not-being-pushed-to-the-rest-of-the-network/110241#comment353775_110241)

Comment: This has now been deployed across all sites.