# Can't edit questions anymore. Is the edit queue full?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I noticed that the "edit" option that used to be beneath a question on SO is missing? 
Right now it only says `link|retag|flag` for all questions I've clicked on.

I read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link) and checked the the 4 points suggested by waffles. I can rule out point 1, 2 and 4. The only thing I can't check (don't know how to) is point 3, the edit queue. Could it be that the edit queue on SO is full?

Comment: You have suggested an edit 6 minutes before you asked this question, and you have just a rejected edit. It is probable the suggestion queue is full.

Comment: There are over 150 edits in the queue right now (157), so yes, it's pretty full.

Comment: Yes the queue which is limited to 160 is full right now. Nick [did warn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110233/privilege-page-updates-not-being-pushed-to-the-rest-of-the-network/110241#comment353845_110241) that things will get slow due to yearly meetup at NYC, guess he was right. :-)

Comment: @Mat, can I check this myself? Or do I need edit privileges (>2000 rep)?

Comment: @THelper you need  more 10000 actually to see the queue, it's part of the "access to moderator tools" privilege.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: No, Suggested Edits can be approved by 2ks as far as I know (I'm 5k on SO, and I can access the queue).

Comment: @Kobobby yes indeed but what happens when you try viewing [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)? :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: There are 99 edits in the queue right now, why do you ask. ;P

Comment: @Kobobby hmm.. so 10K just giving the additional link on top? Grr!!

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: No, I also access the queue via the "review" link. But to end it with pure, naked and hard facts: [2ks are allowed to approve suggested edits, 10ks will only get an additional notice besides the review link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

Answer (score 2):

There are many possiblities such as-

1. You are not logged on and the post is 12 hours old or less
2. There is already a pending edit on this post
3. The queue [is full](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue), only happens rarely on new SE sites with no moderators
4. You have been banned for a week cause you submitted many rejected edits

Options 2, 3 and 4 only apply if you have less than [2,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant with point 1,2 and 4 in my question. The only thing is I don't know how I can check point 3.

Comment: @THelper i didnot have enough permission to check the edit queue, i think mods and high repo user can see it only

Comment: Moderators got little to do with the suggested edits queue - they handle flags, not approving edits. It's the lack of 10K+ members which affect.

Comment: Is there anyway of knowing if `point 4` is true?  And, how many is "too many" rejected edits?