# If I see a typo on a privilege description page, am I expected to inform SO?

Tags: support, spelling, privileges-page

If I see a typo on a privilege description page (or anywhere else), am I expected to inform moderators somehow? Or have I an opportunity to suggest these edits?

Comment: You are at right place! You can inform here.

Comment: As long as it's not a [pluralization bug](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105), sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have I an opportunity to suggest these edits?

<strike>As far as I know we can not suggest edits on privileges page. You can inform it here (Meta Stack Overflow.).</strike>

> (or anywhere else)

But if you are talking about question or answer you can edit it or suggest edit for it.

**EDIT:**
[@Popular Demand answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153060/187824): You can edit privileges on MSO privileges pages.

**Edit2:**

[As per this post by waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66242/187824)

> Temporarily we are allowing all users on meta with more than **2000 reputation** to edit the wikis (of privileges), we will then use these wikis as the global default wikis for all sites.

<sub>Note: Since the post is too old and they used **Temporarily**, the reputation limit may be changed.</sub>

Comment: @PopularDemand I think a user need specific privilege to edit (or suggest edit) privilege pages.

Comment: Then you should have said that.

Comment: @PopularDemand: In this instance it looks like a comment would have been infinitely more constructive at the time.

Comment: @PopularDemand Ahh. When you linked privilege page I did not see `edit wiki` link. But now I can see that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't follow... what comment, at what time?

Comment: ...you haven't bothered to read my answer, have you?

Comment: @PopularDemand: A comment explaining what's wrong with this answer, at the time that you downvoted it. Basic SO etiquette.

Comment: @PopularDemand got it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was busy writing my own answer. Once I finished with that, I went back to leave the comment. Also, I think explaining downvotes is the exception, not the rule. Certainly not "basic SO etiquette."

Comment: @PopularDemand: Sorry to hear you feel that way. I'd have expected more from someone with 30k+ on meta?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to explain a bit more, in this case, I thought the presence of my answer would obviate the need for a comment, since it would show that the existing answer was wrong, and what better reason is there to downvote? If I had commented first, then someone would have replied with "well, why don't you also say what the correct answer is?"

Comment: @PopularDemand: It wasn't clear that the downvote was from you and that it was for the reasons laid out in _your_ answer. And thus it wasn't clear that it was a "legitimate", thought-out downvote. Thus the author of this answer had no idea what was going on until you came back and commented! Personally I'd have immediately written "-1: Sorry but this is not correct -- see my answer" but YMMV I guess.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit alright, fair enough, I still disagree with you but I do see where you're coming from. I think you've been around long enough to have seen it, but for anyone who stumbles across this later, explaining downvotes is discussed extensively at [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) (and the eight dozen questions that link to it).

Comment: @PopularDemand: Indeed. For what it's worth, I don't _always_ explain a downvote, and I respect the right to "anonymous" voting. It's just sometimes that is completely pointless and I believe this was one of those scenarios.

Comment: @PopularDemand Is this the same document you were looking for? (Edit2 on updated answer)

Comment: @hims056 that's a good find. I vaguely feel like they changed the rep limit after that answer was posted, though. You should really have left that comment under my answer, though. It's not a reply to anything in this thread, so people reading here will be confused and people reading the one under my answer won't see it.

Answer (score 6):

The privilege pages are wikis. The "master" copies are located [here, at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges), where they're editable. Changes made to the MSO versions are pushed to the other sites intermittently.

[image]

Comment: I thought this was already documented somewhere, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: And it need two approvers like ordinary tag wikis, or a moderator/dev?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Good question. I _think_ so, but decided not to address it in the answer because I couldn't find documentation. I can't even test it, since I have over 20k MSO rep.

Comment: Well you can do some minor change and see if it's getting through.. if privilege page requires "super approval" it won't. :)

Comment: [See this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66242/187824) about edit privileges wikis.