# Trusted User privileges page is incorrect, or there is a bug

Tags: support, reputation, edits, privileges

[image]

(this image is from the bottom of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user)

Apparently, the Trusted User page says that you need 20k rep to edit the privileges page, but I see "edit wiki" with <5k.

I have tested it, and [I can indeed edit the privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66763/revisions). I did not see a message "You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed." or anything like that; my edit went through instantly.

This is one of the following:

1. a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug); I shouldn't be able to edit the privileges page
2. a typo
3. a historical artifact; the rep requirement changed but it wasn't updated
4. a misplacement; this message was supposed to be on a different privilege
5. a rebellion due to lack of unicorns; they wanted to be included on the privilege page

Which one? (<sup><sub>obviously #5</sub></sup>)

Answer (score 7):

It was [dropped to 2k rep "temporarily"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66242/privilege-wikis-we-need-your-help) so users could help edit the privileges pages into shape, but that "temporarily" never ended apparently...

Not sure if it's meant to be reverted back to 20k or if they decided to leave it permanently...

Comment: ah, ok. well, it doesn't seem to be changing :P

Comment: I actually [edited the wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66605/7) when I was at [1638 rep](http://stackexchange.com/users/1616032/antony?tab=reputation) and it went through without the need of an approval.

Comment: @Antony: There is no suggested edit system for the privileges wikis, but I'm not aware of anything else that would have dropped the reputation requirement further than that... So who knows what it's actually set at then.

Comment: @animuson We should ask a dev then.

Comment: I see the edit button too and I only have 1.2K here.

Comment: Hmm... so this might not be the answer. Unaccepting and investigating

Comment: I made a new account, the edit button doesn't show up with 1 rep