# Review queues on Meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, help-center

On the Stack Overflow help center article about review queues, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), it says on the bottom:

> Note: These two queues do not exist on Meta sites.

But there are Late Answer and First Posts review queues on Meta Stack Overflow, as far as the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) says. So shouldn't that last sentence be removed?

Comment: Those queues don't exist here on this meta.

Comment: @Mat So, are you saying that the specific entry on the privileges page is wrong?

Comment: Yep, it should say something like "Access low quality posts and suggested edits review queues" on MSO but as it stands, only the rep requirement is "flexible" per site while everything else is constant on all sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those privileges are only listed here because Meta serves as the global hub for the privilege wikis. Changes are made to the wikis here, and those changes are eventually pushed across the network to *all* privilege wikis. If you look at a normal privileges page on a Meta site (e.g. [Gaming Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)), there are no privileges listed at all, because privileges are inherited from the parent site.

They *did*, however, change the reputation threshold here on Meta to 2,000 since that is when you gain access to your first review queue *on Meta* (normally the First Posts and Late Answers queues become available at 500 reputation).

Regular users (as well as moderators) can no longer edit these wikis - only developers can. There was a report about that somewhere around here, but I can't find it.

Comment: They're *still* the global hub for privilege wikis: if I want to make changes to a network-wide help page, I have to do it here. They just got less... wikish

Comment: Do you mean this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182651/trusted-user-privileges-page-is-incorrect-or-there-is-a-bug

Comment: @random Yes. Since the privileges pages have been incorporated into the Help Center now, the edit link, and even history link, are no longer available.