# Review help page contains "How do I use the First posts queue?" page, but Meta Stack Exchange doesn't have "First Posts" review queue

Tags: support, bug, review, help-center

Meta Stack Exchange [review help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-queues) contains ["How do I use the First posts queue?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-posts) page, but Meta Stack Exchange doesn't have "First Posts" [review queue itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review).

Also in other site's First Posts review queue page, "Access earned at 500 reputation", but in Meta Stack Exchange it shows "Access earned at 2,000 reputation".

I hope the "First Posts" review queue page is not required for Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't think that we can actually do anything about this. These pages are network-wide and the MSE page is the primary source for content. That said, this also applies to Late answers, I would think - but we're not adding either of these queues to MSE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Review queues on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214705/review-queues-on-meta), it might not be good to target a 7-year old duplicate, but animuson's answer still applies AFAIK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030/282094)