# Please make the revision history of help center articles public

Tags: feature-request, help-center, revisions-list

Please make the revision history of help center articles public to all users. When a non-moderator tries to access the revision history of a help center article ([example](https://askubuntu.com/posts/303613/revisions)), this is shown:

[image: 404 error for a help center revision history link]

I really don't know why revision history of help center articles are hidden to non-moderators. Since non-moderators can see the revision histories of election nomination posts ([example](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1397863/revisions)), the tour page ([example](https://askubuntu.com/posts/239296/revisions)) and [policy locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349276) ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/349276/revisions)), I don't think it makes sense to hide the revision history of help center articles for non-moderators.

Comment: Can you please explain where you see a link to help center page revisions?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Well, we don't see the link of tour page revisions, but it is public.

Comment: The old privilege wiki revision histories are public.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I didn't get you. Can you please share any relevant links?

Comment: Next question: how do you know [this](https://askubuntu.com/posts/303613/revisions) is help center page? Where you got the number "303613" from?

Comment: My point is, we can't ask to change things we shouldn't even be able to see.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard They got it from a moderator. I looked it up, but that's indeed how such links are formatted. Moderators have [2 extra buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE2BP.png) under some help center articles.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I got the number from a mod in Ask Ubuntu. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62014561#62014561

Comment: Prior to the help center rolling out in 2013, the information in the privilege pages for the site used to be stored in a special type of page known as privilege wikis. Those could be edited by 2k+ users here ([was intended to be temporary and changed to 20k+ but it never got changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182651/trusted-user-privileges-page-is-incorrect-or-there-is-a-bug)). They [later got moved to the help center and became non-user-editable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/694491). If you query SEDE for posts with PostTypeId = 8, you'll find some of them.

Comment: Help center pages do have revision histories, but they're only visible to mods. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378449/377214) and its staff comment. (cc @ShadowTheKidWizard)

Comment: That said, if anyone disagrees with this request, can you please point out a good reason why the histories should be hidden from public view? If you believe it's not useful since non-mods aren't linked to it, would you be opposed to having a link to it?

Comment: Meanwhile you can use archive.org.

Comment: @philipxy I agree that we can use archive.org... but since mods can already access the revision history easily, it would be nice if normal users too can see the revision history easily.

Comment: @philipxy Especially for smaller sites, help center pages may not be archived.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The Wayback machine has a nifty little option called Save Page Now (bottom right [here](https://web.archive.org/)) that will archive any page on the internet you want.

Answer (score 31):

This seems like a reasonable request purely in the interests of transparency.

I don't see any reason why the revision history should be private; it doesn't contain any private data or personal information and it's potentially useful as a log of changes in policy.

In most cases, changes to the help center will be publicly hashed out on Meta beforehand, so it's not like the history is exactly hidden anyway.

I'm generally in favor of being transparent when there's no good reason not to be, and that seems to be the case here.

Answer (score -9):

The fact that behind the scenes help center pages are "posts" and stored in the same database table as actual posts on the site, does **not** mean we should be able to see their revisions.

For ordinary posts, we do get link to revisions. Same for nomination posts, there is "history" link.

I see no reason for ordinary users to see the revisions of `/about` (tour) page, or help center pages, which can be edited only by moderators or staff.

Comment: Just because something can only be edited by moderators or staff doesn't mean that such edits shouldn't be auditable by other users.

Comment: There's also the issue of a subset of these pages being copied from the old privilege wikis which could be edited by 2k+ users here, and whose histories prior to that time were (and still are, if one finds the link in SEDE) fully visible to the public. Why should later edits not be publicly visible?

Comment: To readers: Ordinary users can access revisions of `/about` (tour) page.

Comment: What past policy was & when it changed is certainly relevant. The [so] requirement for homework to show answering effort was silently removed from the help, as you can see via the internet archive.

Comment: Having these be non-public also provides an easy way for moderators to abuse their privileges, by taking actions not as per policy, editing the article to indicate that their actions were as per policy, and directing users to the help center when questioned about their actions.

Comment: BTW, nomination posts can't be edited by users other than nominee (maybe mods and staff can), and we can see its revision history. Also, policy locked posts can only be edited by staff and we can see revision history of such posts.

Comment: @RandomPerson about nomination posts, the users who post them are not mods, so allowing only the post author to see revisions would require very complex code changes, which are totally not worth the time.

Comment: @Sonic abuse their power? Really? They can do it with so many other things we can't see, so really doubt they'll choose to abuse their power by injecting spam or bad language in the help center pages.

Comment: @philipxy so we can raise this in the proper meta site, mod can quickly take a look, and post an answer.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Regarding https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1274632, what about policy locked posts? The OPs of such posts are staff and normal users can see the revision history of it.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment on the question. If the help center revisions were already public, would you have any argument to support a feature request to hide them from the public, other than "I don't see why they should be visible since only mods/staff can edit them"? In other words, a philosophical reason they should not be visible, such as confidentiality/privacy related?

Comment: @Random as the policy lock, the post is just ordinary post, I'm pretty sure they can't separate access to revisions only based on a lock, not without complex code changes, which I prefer would be spent elsewhere.

Comment: @Sonic I would consider this as "bug by design" like the ability to answer closed questions for few hours. Semi-hidden feature useful for the few who knows it. But it's one way only.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog *Having these be non-public also provides an easy way for moderators to abuse their privileges* you and others really, seriously, need to stop to, by default, assume moderators abuse their privileges. That you, as a regular user, don't have access to stuff doesn't make it an *abuse* for anyone that can. Please stop that kind of rhetoric. It is counter productive.

Comment: @philipxy if you mean my reply to you, I mean if we want to know when something in help center page has changed,  we can ask moderators, and proper way to do that is by posting a question on the meta site.

Comment: "if we want to know when something in help center page has changed, we can ask moderators" is extremely unworkable.

Comment: @philipxy why? MSO discussion with title like "When were the requirement for homework to show answering effort removed from Help Center?" should be just fine, and raise more attention to it.

Comment: If a mod went to the effort of editing a help page to justify something they said *without* mod and CM awareness, in order to cover up something they did, they ought to be removed. I think we'd have bigger problems if a mod did that @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Comment: @philipxy Regarding the removal of the text about homework in [SO's on-topic page](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): It was removed with just as much fanfare as was given when it was added (actually, the removal appears to have had a bit more fanfare). Requiring homework to have an attempt was never actually policy. An attempt was [*always*](//meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/1) just a recommendation to askers (and a statement of other's likely response), even though a lot of us, including myself, *thought* that it was policy, due to our interpretation of the on-topic page wording.

Comment: @philipxy I know that finding out that an attempt is *not* actually a requirement is jarring, as I was under the impression that homework questions required an attempt from when I first joined SE. The wording in the on-topic page just said that the asker "must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem". That doesn't actually mean that they must have made an attempt, only that they needed to tell us what, *if any*, work they had done. The fact that the on-topic page was so consistently misunderstood by a *lot* of people was the reason to remove that text.

Comment: As the MSO Q&A I linked above describes, there's a large amount of disagreement in the community as to what *should be* required for homework questions on SO (as I recall, there are at least a few, if not several, other Q&A discussing it on MSO, that, eventually, resulted in the Q&A I linked). The text that was in the SO on-topic page was quite open to being (mis)interpreted by users based on their own opinion about what should be required for homework questions. Ultimately, the source of the question which is being asked doesn't really matter to its topicality (baring plagiarism, etc.).

Comment: @Makyen and that's exactly the reason I said it's better to raise such things on the meta site (asking mods for the reason Help Center page was changed), your comments would make a great answer, and here they might be lost any moment.

Comment: @Makyen An attempt was most definitely required at one point in the past. There used to be a close reason for questions without attempts, which [said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256020/2157772), *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).* Point number 2 in the linked checklist states an attempt.

Comment: @Sonic I don't understand why you're bringing up a completely different close reason (debugging, which *does* require enough to duplicate the problem, but is the *only* type of question that requires that) and general guidance, which says merely that you should have "explained what you've already tried", but *doesn't* say that you actually need to have tried anything (i.e. "I haven't tried to solve this", or "I'm unsure how to start in on this" *is* explaining what you've tried, which is nothing), in order to state there was a *requirement* for there to be an attempt in homework problems.

Comment: @Makyen I'm not bringing up a different close reason. Back in that time, there were two close reasons: one for "questions asking about problems with code you've written" and one for "questions asking for code". The modern reason equates to the former; the latter was entirely removed and is the one I'm mentioning.