# Should the wiki page for moderator-tools privileges contain a message about not deleting duplicates?

Tags: discussion, privileges

I think the [wiki page for moderator tools privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) should contain a note about [not deleting duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates) and the reasons why having duplicates is actually a good thing.

I don't have edit privileges for these pages. Perhaps someone who does can make this change if appropriate.

Comment: With regards to the editing capability, see the comments on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message/66241#66241).

Comment: I've added a short blurb. Feel free to modify...

Comment: @Shog9: Can't see anything there. Has someone rolled it back?

Comment: [apparently, edits don't actually *show up* anywhere...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66326/revisions)