# I have new privileges; what prevents me from mis-using them?

Tags: discussion, privileges

I've now gained enough rep to be able to close questions, edit everywhere, and review.

What is there to prevent me from abusing my powers?  (i.e. from voting to close good questions)

The intent of this question is to learn how to use my powers for good; I've already read the FAQ and the pages on when to edit, close, etc.  But I still don't understand it all that well.

**Whose responsibility is it to correct me, if I go astray?**

**Is there a way to get feedback on whether I'm voting to close good questions?**

Comment: How many users can you count with the ability to flag?

Comment: @random -- I don't understand; what do you mean?

Comment: If you go astray, other users will see and alert the moderators through flags and you may face a timeout

Comment: @random -- can you flag somebody for voting to close too many questions?

Comment: Kind of related: ["You have gained power. Here's how to use it." kind of message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message)

Comment: Use your powers sparingly. If you see something fishy, go for it, otherwise, refrain. And be nice to newbees.

Comment: Ah, and don't vote to close questions of mine!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Star every question you vote to close (or bookmark it locally, or write down its ID...). Check on them in a few hours. Did anyone else vote to close? If yes, you're probably doing it right; if no, you're probably not.

If too many people are voting to close inappropriately, people eventually start complaining here on MSO and raising mod flags, and then mods can look to see if the same few people are involved in numerous bad closings.