# Create an automatic notification or comment to the questions of users who can vote, but who do not use the privilege

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many new users on Stack Overflow don't understand the meaning of the right of "vote up" for answers or questions. At the beginning (until they reach 15 reputation points) the user can't "vote up". Later some users don't use the right and don't really understand it.

I suggest that the users who have the right to vote and do not use it will receive automatic comments on their new questions with links to topics describing the voting. One can define the starting point of the comment generation either as 15 points or some higher level (like 30 point) or a more complex rule. One can make the rule depend on the total number of asked questions for example.

In the same way many people who do not accept any answers on their questions do this just because they do not know how to accept the answers or because they do not understand that accepting is really important. So instead of writing the messages (comments) manually with links to [the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5235/147495) for example the Stack Overflow could generate the comments automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea for two reasons:

1. Comments aren't the right place to give users instructional messages.
2. [Users are already notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66241/153020) privately, directly when they get new privileges.

Comment: Probably I never seen the batch notification or the notification will be produced only one and the user not read it carefully. In any way the existing way seems not work. So I have to write regularly such comments myself with the links described how to accept or vote. After that the user do use the features. An example are my comments to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092272/canceling-post-of-row-data-when-inline-editing-finished-per-row-post) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193342/how-do-i-set-doubleclick-function-to-call-custom-function-in-jqgrid).

Comment: What if the comment was only visble to the person that asked the quesion?