# Include mini-tutorial when a new privilege is earned

Tags: feature-request, notifications, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You have gained power. Here's how to use it.” kind of message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message)

I have recently earned a small amount of reputation (~300) in SO but find myself a little unfamiliar with the proper use of my new-found powers without performing a bit of searching around on metaSO.

Perhaps when certain privileges are earned (downvote, edit, etc.) not only could a notice of "Hey you earned XYZ!" appear but also a couple links to "Helpful meta-questions related to this privilege" which would link to highly voted questions on that privilege.  This would be in addition to the FAQ page.

My issue is that the FAQ page is excellent for each privilege, however, sometimes community discussion on these topics is needed to remove any remaining confusion on proper use. This feature should probably be implemented in a fashion other than I described but I think what I am suggesting is clear.

Comment: Doh! Couldn't find this other post!

Comment: It sounds to me like those FAQ pages just need links to the related discussion, which we can already edit in via the [meta privilege pages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges), if need be. It'd be better, however, if you just pointed out parts you were confused about so we can edit those pieces of the wiki rather than needing links to other information.