# What is considered appropriate tag use?

Tags: discussion, tags

After a big hoo-haa about purported tag-abuse recently, I thought I'd try and clarify things here.

"why not keep the existing question"?

I deleted it; it was too personal about one individual, which isn't fair when that "event" has been dealt with already.

So; to clarify; in my opinion (and I welcome other views):

- tags categorise problems by technology (`java`) / subject (`serialization`) / product (`oracle`), etc - although obviously this meaning changes slightly per-site
- they aren't an IM tool
- they shouldn't be used to target *individuals* as a way to receive questions

So; if you see any user-specific tags, please either edit them out, or if there are lots - flag for a moderator (we might be able to merge them into a related technology).

I'd welcome any other ideas, but no heads on spikes please.

Comment: Shouldn't this be added to the FAQ?

Comment: This seems like something that could be more easily handled with a SQL job once in a while... search for tags that match user names and flag them for moderation.

Comment: select tags.* from tags inner join users on tags.tagname = users.username where tags.tagname not like 'jon skeet'

Comment: @TheTXI: Jeff deletes the 'jon skeet' tag on a regular basis. :)

Comment: @Billy the Reptile: It should be automated and it should ban users who create it again.

Comment: I seem to miss all the "hoo-haa"s.  Care to post a link?

Comment: @tv: It is still being cried about on twitter. http://twitter.com/jlward4th

Comment: I am simply fascinated that someone actually had the ego and the lack of common sense to even make this an issue.

Comment: I agree this should be added to the FAQ

Comment: @TheTXI - Exploit. What happens to your `select` when I change my name to "python"?

Comment: @rcar: We ban you for gross incompetence.

Comment: @rcartaino -- or when Jon Skeet changes his to "Jon Skeet'; DROP TABLE Users; --"

Comment: I don't think this was handled in the correct way.  Common sense dictates that warnings are appropriate in this situation, especially when the user was without malice.  Not every one that uses SO is a power user, like you guys seem to be, and know all of the subtle rules. Suspending accounts and deleting discussion threads only inflame the issue, when a simple direct message probably would have been the best for everyone.  This is a community issue, not a policy issue.

Comment: @zachleat: The user was warned. The abuse and spam was cleaned up. He got a one day account suspension for the volume. I think this was handled well.

Comment: Well, I humbly disagree. I think the process could be improved. How was I to find this post from the deleted one?  If you find it acceptable to delete the conversation, at least forward to the appropriate venue where the issue can be discussed and addressed.

Comment: @zachleat: First, the old conversation was completely off topic. This one is not. Second, that thread turned into a flamefest as the user in question decided to recruit new users to flame moderators and members while he stoked the flames on twitter. This kind of behavior is in sharp contrast to your claims, but we all watched it unfold.

Comment: @Zachleat: Also, it was 'discussed and addressed'. The abuse and spam was removed from the site, the user was warned and penalized, and it was explained to him both by the community and by the moderators.

Comment: Just for the record - my hands are clean; I was involved in neither the original thread nor the suspension. I'm just trying to clean up the pieces...

Comment: How does the moderation of tags help the community?  If the developer community likes using certain tags and those tags help bring more developers to SO then what is the harm in having them?

Comment: @James - given the hugely negative response from both the community and the site owners, I think we've shown that the "developer community" as very anti-this. What you mean is "If I like using...". And the resounding answer is "just no".

Comment: @Marc Every developer I've talked to likes the idea.  It is only the SO moderator community that seems to have a problem with this.  MSO is not where most developers I talk to hang out.  Most don't even hang out on SO.  Which is why I'm trying to find ways to get more developers I know using SO.  Perhaps the developer community that I hang out in and the SO community are just incompatible are we can just leave it at that?

Comment: If "most don't even hang out on SO", I'm not sure that they can have a sensible opinion over whether it is appropriate or not. Pretty much everyone who has been involved in these 2 threads is strongly against. I think bringing in more developers is fine and commendable - but why the ridiculous tagging? Sorry, but it is simply inappropriate. It is a *community*. If they want to ask a question about (say) "ria", than ask the *community* about "ria". If you want people to contact **you**, then SO isn't the place; give them your e-mail address.

Comment: We'd love the extra heads, but not at the price of actively damaging the site.

Comment: I guess that is where the opinions of the developer I hang out with differ from the SO moderators.  Every developer I've talked to feels that it enhances SO not damages it.  So it does seem there is just simple incompatibility here.  That's fine.  We can leave it at that.

Comment: @James: I would hate to see what developers don't understand the tagging concept and would like to see it abused. I for one would rather do without this audience.

Comment: @Rich Obviously you and the community I hang out in have differing opinions about the purpose of tagging.  Lets just leave it at that.  No kittens were harmed.  We can move on now.

Comment: @James: But you seem to have trouble separating **your** community from **this** community. That is a huge problem when you want to dictate upon **this** community what **your** community desires.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to address (in as general a way as I can) the issue of tags being used as an IM tool, I'd say it's much better to use established tags that the community has created rather than create your own specific tag.  We don't need tags that "Bat Signal" individual users.  Stack Overflow (and its sister sites) has many experts in many domains.  If you want your own following of readers to be able to get the full benefit from Stack Overflow, tell them what tags you subscribe to.  That way they can get the benefit of the entire community that follows those tags, not just the attention of one individual.

Comment: someone deleted the `alan-kay` tag :( **Get the pirchforks!!!**

Comment: @voyager: I'm kind of on the fence on that.  I think setting the bar at "Turing Award winner" is high enough that we won't be inundated with *too* many user-specific tags.  On the other hand, you can still do a user search for "Alan Kay" and find him.  No harm done in deleting it.

Comment: The tag serves no purpose and only muddies the water with people who want to argue.

Comment: @Rich B: Agreed.  It would just open up the "appeal to common practice" argument, despite the lofty height of the bar.

Comment: @Willy the Iguana: Right, especially when this particular user has the kind of ego where I think he would argue he is above that bar.

Answer (score 10):

When you ask a question, the title field has:

> What's your programming question? Be descriptive.

Given the recent brouhaha over the tags, maybe it would be a good idea to include such a reminder next to the tags field. Something like:

> What technology, product or subject matter is the question about?

Comment: I am not sure that one or maybe a few people having no common sense is cause for yet *another* reminder/warning.

Answer (score 5):

Too bad there's not a media site.  Then I could change my username to `tv` and get to have/keep my own tag.

Comment: I suppose you *could* just change your username to asp.net-mvc.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this?

Comment: @tv: Why would anyone **not**?

Comment: @Rich B -- a sense of humor?

Comment: @tv: After a 'joke' like that, I don't think you are in the place to be telling anyone to get a sense of humor. Also, complaining about down votes to a joke answer on meta, it doesn't get lamer than that.

Comment: @Rich B -- you take things too seriously.

Comment: @tv: Yes. I have never been known to joke around. I don't find your joke funny, so clearly I have no sense of humor.

Comment: @Rich B -- I wasn't accusing you of not having a sense of humor.  It just amazed me that someone would care enough about it to actually downvote it (or upvote it for that matter).  I don't get the kind of thinking that says "I have to express my opinion on everything."  Faced with the same situation, I would simply move on instead of expressing a negative opinion.

Comment: @tv: "Care enough to downvote"? It is one click man. I care enough to vote on everything, just like people should.

Comment: @Rich B -- but you seem to find much more to vote down, than up.  That's another kind of thinking I don't get.

Comment: @tv: You are the kind of person **I** don't get. Why do my voting patterns concern you? Have you thought that when you do mostly editing that you end up on all the crappiest portions of the site, and not only in the portions of the site you want to play with? I am not paralyzed by politeness to not edit or down vote something when necessary to help keep the site clean.

Answer (score -2):

You could also add 'they aren't a flagging tool', e.g. don't use 'belongs-on-serverfault' (if there is a consensus - see e.g. [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/change-the-belongs-on-serverfault-tag-when-a-question-is-moved-to-serverfault)).

Guidelines on use of 'off-topic', 'subjective', 'not-programming-related' (if they should be used! - see e.g. [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/when-should-a-question-with-the-subjective-tag-not-be-a-community-wiki)) could also be useful.

Comment: IM aspect was like tagging it with the name or site of the person you wanted to answer your question so that they could just check the tag as their own inbox.

Comment: @random: Thanks for the clarification.