# Am I annoying the mods with my flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

Yesterday, I were [flaging some tag abuse, some continous spamming by the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17706/what-is-considered-appropriate-tag-use) user and some poorly worded questions.

At one point I started making silly jokes, hoping that the same mod would view them.

Am I abusing the system by trying to amuse the mods while at the same time trying to improve the site? Would this be OK, if only my jokes weren't so bad?

Answer (score 6):

Only if your flags are bad. If your flags are legit then the more we get the better.

Comment: Can any of the mods that have seen any of my flags attest if I'm flagging badly?

Comment: If you are making poor jokes and small erotic novella to bring attention to things you should probably leave that to Welbog and his love letters to bill the lizard

Comment: Can mods even see who flagged them? I know that 10k rep users can't, bt that's a different level of course.

Comment: Yes we can see who flags

Answer (score 6):

> Am I abusing the system by trying to amuse the mods while at the same time trying to improve the site?

No, a few other people do that, too.  There's a limit on the number of characters you can write, so if you have room left over after you've fully explained the issue, go ahead and make me laugh.  (I reserve the right to use your best material and pretend that I thought of it myself.)

---

#### Note:

**Yes Welbog, for christ's sake, I like vanilla ice cream already!!!**

Comment: Why are you afraid to say welbog's name? Are you ashamed that you've fallen hopelessly in love with his laserness?

Comment: @TheTXI: I don't want Welbog walking around thinking we're *exclusive* or anything.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest Haiku flags:

> I've seen this before...
>
> Duplicate of duplicate.
>
> Merge, for God's sake, merge!