# Remove "belongs on X" comments when migrating

Tags: feature-request, comments, migration

I personally think it would be really cool if there was some little thing that ran that deleted all comments similar to `belongs on <site migrated to>` when the question is migrated.

When they finally do get migrated, these comments just add noise..

Comment: Show us the regex for it. ;)

Comment: Doesn't this happen already?

Comment: @Juan You're thinking of the auto-tag removal like here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/change-the-belongs-on-serverfault-tag-when-a-question-is-moved-to-serverfault

Comment: oh... **comments**, right

Answer (score 2):

There are too many variants for this to be feasible in a mechanically automated system. You'd have to watch for "you should ask this on X" or "this should be at X" or "SO is not the place for these, try X", and hundreds of variations. Way too many, and if you try to catch all of them it'll cause too much crossover with potentially legitimate posts. And if the scope is too small, you'll still end up with a lot of comments missed.

Just flag the question post-migration. Maybe even get the moderator to fix retags on the source site's corresponding post while they're around, if necessary.

Comment: I agree, but that makes me think it might be practical to just check for any comments containing the name of the migrated-to and flag them for manual review.

Comment: Could you not simply: Upon migration to site XYZ.com flag all comments that include literal "XYZ.com". That way, the moderators would at least see them.

Comment: Auto-flagging makes sense, as long as it is flagging. As long as we aren't making the gardening process entirely mechanical and pruning comments without human input.

Comment: @devinb I'd be surprised if you didn't get pinged for this

Comment: I did not get pinged. thanks for looking into the issue.

Comment: @devinb *This* time, I will be honestly surprised if you don't get pinged.

Comment: Score! It totally worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: @devinb No problem, glad to be able to help.